# How to access a collection element in imported JSON file?

Tags: angular

I have the following json file 'firestore-export.json' exported from Firestore:

```
{
    "Projects": {
        "2iAwxh23EhZmzQpqcR4c": {
            "title": "Test1",
            "description": "abc",
            "id": "2iAwxh23EhZmzQpqcR4c"
        },
        "3iAwxh23EhZmzQpqcR4c": {
            "title": "Test2",
            "description": "def",
            "id": "3iAwxh23EhZmzQpqcR4c"
        }
    },
    "Users": {
        "6iAwxh23EhZmzQpqcR4c": {
            "name": "User1",
            "id": "6iAwxh23EhZmzQpqcR4c"
        },
        "7iAwxh23EhZmzQpqcR4c": {
            "name": "User2",
            "id": "7iAwxh23EhZmzQpqcR4c"
        }
    }
}
```

How to access the first project in Angular 8?

import db from './firestore-export.json';
project = db.Projects.???

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) then access 1st item in array by index:

```js
const Projects = Object.values(db.Projects);

console.log(Projects[0]);
```

or using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to retrieve all keys:

```js
const keys = Object.keys(db.Projects);
const first = keys[0];

console.log(db.Projects[first]);
```